# Alternative to Runscope Traffic Inspector

Tags: http, scope, inspector

Runscope will unfortunately remove from their products the traffic inspector, now I'm looking for an alternative that:

can work in a docker
 and has a web interface where you can see the requests and responses

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://trafficlens.io. It's a traffic inspector with built with security in mind. It uses the same url-based approach like runscope so it's as simple as switching the url

Full disclosure: We built it as a replacement for runscope after the announcement.

Comment: Looks like the site is down or deprecated?

Comment: We relaunch as https://apitracker.com/. Please email me at trung@apitracker.com and we'll create you an account

Comment: This is not how Runscope Traffic Inspector worked. Not even close. You require to drop some code at the consumer side and also only supporting Python and NodeJs at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://requestinspector.com/ for same. Not a very good alternative but can be used to track requests.

Answer (score 1):

I created CurlHub which is a knock off of the beloved Runscope inspector. I spent a lot of time comparing it against Runscope before it closed down.

One big difference is we don't save your proxied requests for better or worse (for GDPR reasons), they're saved in your browser so it has to be open for the requests to be captured.

Sign up for a free trial
https://curlhub.io

Answer (score 0):

Moesif has a live event stream to look at HTTP calls. It focuses more on the API analytics side rather than testing and has SDKs that can work in dockerized apps.

Full disclosure: I work for Moesif.